# Cross referencing with Dataview webpart

Tags: 2010, list, filter, data-view-web-part

Oh man I must be losing my mind but I can't for the life of me figure this out. I have a list called "Stuff" and a library called "Stuff documents". "stuff documents" has a lookup column to the title of "Stuff". So each item in "stuff" has corresponding "stuff documents".

This is in the same site.

So what I want to do, is on the display form for "Stuff", I want to add a DVWP or a LVWP under the item view that shows "stuff documents". (I got this done np). Now I'd like to filter "stuff documents" dvwp to only show documents where "stuff document's lookup value" = current item's title.

So for example if there's an item in "stuff" called "sports", and I have 2 of 10 documents in "stuff documents" that have lookup value set to "sports". When user clicks on "sports" from "stuff" list, I want them to see webpart with 2 documents listed under the properties for sports.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow this forum is a ghost town. Five views in 3 days. Probably all mine. Anyway, the solution was to just link the DVWP to original list webpart.

Found answer here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/54c07902-ad47-4f8d-ad9c-5e8d0acd8fec/having-trouble-filtering-data-view-inserted-on-dispformaspx-by-field-value-already-on-the-page?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy